# I am getting a 404 error when running Django admin on Chrome but works on Microsoft Edge

Tags: python, django

[image]My Django admin was working fine, when I added the Allauth then the admin is not working on chrome and internet explorer but works fine on Microsoft edge. What could be the problem.

```
urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('product.urls' , namespace='products')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more about the the chrome error. i.e. Maybe some screen shot of your error etc

Comment: I have edited the picture. Check it out.

Comment: show your urls.py

Comment: @shoytov i have added the urls.py

Comment: could that be a missing `/` at the end of the URL? (`http://127.0.0.1/admin` to `http://127.0.0.1/admin/`)

Comment: It really is. So silly of me. Thank you very much.